# Universal Links: Exclude paths starting with

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I have successfully set up Universal Links in my app, I have something like:

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
        {
            "appID": "MyAppId.com.example.test",
            "paths": [ "*"]
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now I'd like to exclude certain Urls starting with, for instance, *top_secret*. So por ejemplo, considering the domain is *www.example.com*, I'd like my App to open:

- www.example.com/path/subpath
- www.example.com/path/subpath/subsubpath

But I don't want it to open:

- www.example.com/path/subpath/top_secret123/sudssubpath
- www.example.com/path/subpath/top_secret123
- www.example.com/path/subpath/top_secret456789/sudssubpath

Is there a way to do so by using the *NOT* keyword?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use NOT Keyword to exclude some paths like :

```
{
"applinks": {
 "apps": [],
 "details": [
    {
        "appID": "MyAppId.com.example.test",
        "paths": [ "*","NOT */top_secret*/*"]
    }
   ]
  }
}
```

Comment: it's not working for me, the App still opens the path. There could be several subpaths till getting to the string "top_secret", like www.example.com/subpath1/subpath2/subpatch3/../top_secret1213/more_subpaths/...

Comment: Add the "NOT " first. The docs mention that it will consider the first match in the list.